# Face detection not working using methods from API14

Tags: android, camera, detection

I have a problem with face detection methods from API14. I have not null camera object. I set to it listener using `setFaceDetectionListener` with very simple implementation of FaceDecectionListener.

I next step I call camera.startFaceDetection() but inteface method `onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera)` is never call... What's wrong with this simple method? Maybe there's a problem with camera? I tested this function on SGS3 and SGS4 and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK guys, issue solved. Not all devices supports face detection function from camera preview. It's device-dependent. Some of devices can crash with message like `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid face detection type=0` but some devices do nothing and listener's method is never reached.

In this case it's needed to check that device support this function using `Camera.getMaxNumDetectedFaces()`. If this method returns 0 then we can be sure that our device does not support face detection methods from API14.

Comment: My device returned 35, and still threw the error. :-( So be aware that your mileage may vary.