# Invalid face detection type=0 error throws on certain devices - Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have xamarin.forms android project app with a custom camera view. I am using `Camera.IFaceDetectionListener`  for detecting faces in the camera preview. It works fine on most of the devices. But in certain devices it throws exception which says `invalid face detection type=0` after calling

```
Control.Preview.SetFaceDetectionListener(this);
Control.Preview.StartFaceDetection();
```

After some googling saw some SO post says some devices does not support face detection.

From this post [Face detection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011319/face-detection-not-working-using-methods-from-api14) , there is a way to check a device whether it support face detection or not by using `Camera.getMaxNumDetectedFaces()`. How exactly can I use this in xamarin? Or is there any other way to solve this issue? Because my app gets crashed when starting the Face detection. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine if the device supports facial recognition.

You could try to use this before you `StartFaceDetection();`

```
CameraManager cManager = (CameraManager)GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);
string cId = (int)CameraFacing.Front + "";
CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cManager.GetCameraCharacteristics(cId);
int maxCount = (int)cameraCharacteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.StatisticsInfoMaxFaceCount);
```

If `maxCount = 0` then we can be sure that our device does not support face detection

Comment: Thanks Leo. I will try your solution. I also get count by this way .   var CameraParaMeters = cameraPreview.camera.GetParameters();  var count=CameraParaMeters.MaxNumDetectedFaces.   Is it correct way?

Comment: It's also correct,but it seems to be the obsolete api in `Camera` .We recommend using the new `android.hardware.camera2` API for new applications after api 21.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. One more doubt, does this API will stop work in android 11 ?